# Concatenating 2d numpy arrays to a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have large set of 2d arrays which are being created with loop.

```
>>> for x in list_imd:
...     arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(x)
...     print arr.shape
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
(129, 135)
```

I want to convert these 2d arrays into one 3d array.

```
>>> arr_stacked.shape
(19, 129, 135)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the simple [`numpy.array` constructor](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.array([arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(x) for x in list_imd])
```

---

Here is an example that works by me:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]])

>>> np.array([a, a]).shape
(2, 2, 3)
```